# Get position off all divs

Tags: javascript, html, position

I want get the the position (screen coordinates) of all divs in an iframe using javascript. No jQuery.

I can get all the divs in an array like this:

```
var arr = window.frames[0].document.getElementsByTagName("div");
```

Then i tried to do:

```
var arr = window.frames[0].document.getElementsByTagName("div").x;
```

But it didn't work. Console logs undefined. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
var divs = window.frames[0].document.getElementsByTagName("div")
    i = 0, rects = [];
for (; i < divs.length; i++)
    rects.push(divs[i].getBoundingClientRect());
```

Now the array `rects` contains objects that define the position *relative to the viewport* of all your divs. Each of the elements will be something like this:

```
{
    top: ...,
    right: ...,
    bottom: ...,
    left: ...,
    width: ...,
    height: ...
}
```

Those properties are the number of pixel from each border (or the width or height).

IE6-8 don't report the `width` and `height` properties, though, but it's easy to compute them.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByTagName` returns an array.  The array object has no `x` property.

You will need to iterate over the members, collecting each value of `x`.

Furthermore (as pointed out in comments below), divs don't have an `x` property.  See
the question "[Retrieve the position (X,Y) of an HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element)" for details on how to manage that.

Comment: Each div won't have an x property either.

Comment: is there any way i can do this without using jQuery .each. Using a loop or something?

Comment: the word is offset...and the above answer is not an answer.its a comment

Comment: @MattSach That's true.  I'll edit accordingly.